# Batch Script to get file modified info

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to write a batch script for use on an XP machine.
I basically want to get the file modified info for a particular file and output it to a file.

Here is what I have written so far:

```
SET filename="C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\testfile.txt"
 if exist %filename% (
    for %%A in (%filename%) DO (SET "bodytext=%bodytext%testfile.txt updated at %%~tA")
)
  else (
   SET "bodytext=%bodytext%Warning no file exists." 
 )
echo %bodytext% > results.txt
```

When I run it, it writes the updated file name  nand time fine to results.txt, but it also writes "Warning no file exists." to results.txt also?

I would be very grateful if anyone can help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
)
  else (
```

This must be all on one line

) else (

Comment: Thanks for the reply, cant believe it was that simple!

Answer (score -1):

you must use 'setlocal enabledelayedexpansion' if you set variables inside 'for' command.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET filename="C:\filename.txt"
if exist %filename% (
    for %%a in (%filename%) do (
        set filedate=%%~ta
        set bodytext=%filename% last updated at !filedate!
    )
) else (
    set bodytext=%filename% No File Exist.
)

echo %bodytext%>c:\results.txt
```

Comment: Delayed expansion has nothing to do with the OP's problem. Your addition of the `filedate` variable does require delayed expansion, but it is a totally unnecessary complication.

Comment: Yes it works, and you have totally obfuscated the OP's actual problem and added complexity where it is not needed. The reason this works and the OP's does not is because you have combined the `else (` with the `)` line above. Make only that change to the OP's code (without delayed expansion), and it works just fine, as Magoo describes in his answer.